# Rails Error: Unable to access log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, whenever

I suddenly got this error at my app which ran without problems for more than two years:

```
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that .../production.log exists...   
WARN -- : Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen .../log/newrelic_agent.log
```

The result of this error is that my mongoDB is killed. After I restarted the app everything works again until scheduled tasks are called which lead to that behaviour.

The error message says that i have to chmod to 0664, but this is still the case. For the deployment I use capistrano.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure what the log folder is existed on the remove server? I mean is that folder linked by capistrano before Rails server started?

Comment: Yes the folder exists. like i mentioned. it ran with this configuration for more than two years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know the reason for that strange behaviour: Hard Disk Failure !!!
Even both Disks were dead at the same time (RAID1) :(

Answer (score 1):

Make log directory writable for other users:

```
chmod -R 777 specify_app_path_here/log
```